# 本番環境でレイアウトが崩れる（CSSが機能しない）

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails5/pumaを使用しており、検証環境から本番環境へ、環境を移行させようとしています。
下記の通り、アセットのプリコンパイル及びサーバ起動を行いましたが、レイアウトが崩れました。
解決方法を教えていただきたく、質問させていただきます。

◆ コマンド

```
$ rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
$ rails c
  Running via Spring preloader in process 29262
  Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
  irb(main):001:0> Rails.application.config.assets.prefix
   => "/assets"
$ sudo [プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/shims/pumactl start RAILS_ENV=production
```

◆ ブラウザアクセス
    [https://[ドメイン名]/assets/typeaheadjs.self-027337105ed5038b2f54f30159dab8ca30455083b1e0e02b1571387488b874ea.css](https://[%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E5%90%8D]/assets/typeaheadjs.self-027337105ed5038b2f54f30159dab8ca30455083b1e0e02b1571387488b874ea.css)

◆ エラーログ（ブラウザ）

```
Puma caught this error: undefined method `silence' for #<Logger:0x007f1e61f587b0> (NoMethodError)
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:11:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
[プロジェクト名]/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo [プロジェクト名] RAILS_ENV=production ./rbenv/shims/pumactl start 
RAILS_ENV=productionをpumactlの前においてはどうですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。試してみたところ、production環境での起動ができました。（いままでできていなかったことに気づきました…）
しかし、CSSのレイアウト崩れは治りませんでした。
新たに発生したエラーが以下の通りです。


Install the mechanize gem version ~>2.7.5 for using mechanize functions.
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
* Listening on ssl://0.0.0.0:443?cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/[ドメイン名]/fullchain.pem&key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/[ドメイン名]/privkey.pem&verify_mode=none
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Error in reactor loop escaped: no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)

Comment: enviroment環境で問題ないなら、production環境ではbundle installしたものを使ってない？削除して再度bundle install --path vendor/bundle実行する？production環境では前処理(rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV,)

Comment: 等)が必要らしいですけど？あまり、内容は理解できていません。ポートが3000になっているのも気になります。私が言えることはこれぐらいです。

Comment: ご確認いただきありがとうございます。
あれからいろいろ調べてみたところ、プリコンパイルした(publicディレクトリ内)のcss等がRouting Errorを起こして読み込めていないことがわかりました。
上品ではないですが、「config/environments/production.rb」に以下を追加することで、解消しました。
config.public_file_server.enabled = true